# Using unbound form to enter data

Tags: ms-access

I have a main form (bound to a table) and unbound form that is used for selection a value in one of the main form's required fields. Main form has three required fields (firstName, lastName, source) and unbound form is used to display all sources that can be selected by the user so when the user confirms source it will automatically insert this information in the main form's bound table.

I've figured out the code for existing records and my unbound form successfully inserts updated source. However the problem are new records. Because source is required field, the main form won't let me open unbound form since it detects that not all fields are entered for the new record.

I tried using this piece of code when user clicks on a button to select the source (by opening unbound form):

```
If (Me.Dirty) Then
    Me.Dirty = False
End If
```

to avoid being asked to enter the third piece of information before going to an unbound form that will allow user to input this data, however i get an exception that tells me that I cannot leave the form apparently without entering the source.

Is this a common problem and how would one go around solving it? I understand that it is easier just to use bound command on the main form but since selecting sources can be confusing I thought it would be better to actually create a second form so that the user could correctly select the source when saving new or updating existing records.

Comment: Try setting a `DefaultValue` for the source in the bound form.

Comment: Thanks. Putting default value does work. It did cross my mind to take that path however I was afraid that users could make a mistake and skip setting this field if they notice a default value in it. But I guess I need to have more faith in their intelligence.

Comment: No, I don't think this is common problem because the arrangement is unconventional. Why aren't you using combobox or listbox on main form?

Comment: I tried using combo box that lists all job sources on the main form but I ran into several issues. First, the cbo became pretty large very fast as it was showing all open and closed job sources (from job ads) in the past. Second, If I limit cbo to show only open (current) job sources then old candidates would have empty cbo because their sources have been closed in the past. I tried a solution where I would show only open jobs to new candidates during the record creation, and then once the record is saved the source for the cbo would change to displaying all closed and open job sources.